# jquery AJAX won't display returned HTML asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to use a web method to load a block of HTML after the page has been loaded.  The following code is returning an object, however it won't append to the returned HTML to the div "tabs" on success.  The "Callerdt" variable below is a data table that was loaded from the database. Any ideas why it won't append the HTML to the div tag?  Do you think the HTML string being passed is too large?  Please let me know if you need more info and thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var p = document.getElementById('pn').value, u = document.getElementById('user').value, er = document.getElementById('error').value;

        if (!(er == "true" && u == "false" && p == "false")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'CallerPopup.aspx/LoadPatients',
                data: JSON.stringify({ phone: p, user: u }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#tabs').append(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

---

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string LoadPatients(string phone, string user)
        {
            var ret = "No Patients Found";
...
                //generate html to display patient details
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                string addr = "";
                for (int x = 0; x < Callerdt.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    addr = Callerdt.Rows[x]["Street"].ToString() + " " + Callerdt.Rows[x]["city"].ToString() + ", " + Callerdt.Rows[x]["State"].ToString() + " " + Callerdt.Rows[x]["ZipCode"].ToString();
                    sb.AppendFormat("<div class='tabs'><table>" +
                                    "<tr><td class='title'><label>Name:</label></td><td>{0}</td></tr>" +
                                    "<tr><td><label>DOB:</label></td><td>{1}</td></tr>" +
                                    "<tr><td><label>Address:</label></td><td>{2}</td></tr>" +
                                    "<tr><td><label>SSN:</label></td><td>{3}</td></tr>" +
                                    "<tr><td><label>Z Number:</label></td><td>{4}</td></tr>" +
                                    "</table></div><br/>", Callerdt.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString(), Callerdt.Rows[x]["DOB"].ToString(), addr, Callerdt.Rows[x]["SSN"].ToString(), Callerdt.Rows[x]["ZNUM"].ToString());
                }
                ret = sb.ToString();
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: Your return data type is wrong, change the dataType to html

Comment: change dataType: "json" to dataType: "html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses.  I finally managed to get it to work by doing the following.  I noticed while debugging in chrome that there was a json object being returned called 'd'.  So I tried the following and now it's working great!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var p = document.getElementById('pn').value, u = document.getElementById('user').value, er = document.getElementById('error').value, un = document.getElementById('usernum').value;
        if (!(er == "true")) {
            $("#loading").show()
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'CallerPopup.aspx/LoadPatients',
                data: JSON.stringify({ phone: p, user: u, usernum: un }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#tabs').append(data.d);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'CallerPopup.aspx/LoadPatients',
                data: JSON.stringify({ phone: p, user: u }),
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#tabs').append(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I tried this and was getting weird results.  For some reason, instead of just going to the webmethod, it was redoing the page_load and resulting in an infinite loop because the ajax call was in $.ready

Comment: you can send me your response?